# Iterate through an array to match result

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have an array where any of the elements could have a match with a mongodb collection.

```
  var elementsArray = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];

  db.getCollection("myCollections").aggregate([
    ...
    { $group: {...} },
    {
      $match: {
         for(item in elementsArray ){ // this for loop is not appropriate but to give the idea          
           $or:[
              { "word": item  },
              { "preferredWord": item },
              { "synonym": item }
           ],
         }
       }
    }
 ])
```

I know the for loop is inappropriate here but how can iterate through the elementsArray to find a match with any of the keywords (word, preferredWord, or synonym) that can perform the similar operations if the for loop was allowed like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can run your array outside of `Aggregate`, by just creating an array and including it inside of your `Aggregate` query:

```
var elementsArray = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];

var orArray = [];

for (item in elementsArray ) {
    orArray.push( { "word": elementsArray[item], "preferredWord": elementsArray[item], "synonym": elementsArray[item] } );
}
```

Then you can use `orArray` object inside your `aggregate`:

```
db.getCollection("myCollections").aggregate([
...
{ $group: {...} },
{
  {
   $match: {
        "$or" : orArray
   }
}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$in` *aggregation operator* to match a field with elements from the array. You can add the other aggregation stages *where appropriate* (I cannot specify the entire query without the definition of the collection's input document)

**Example `matches` collection:**

```
{ _id: 1, fld1: "blah", word: "item2", synonym: "item3" }
{ _id: 2, fld1: "zzz", word: "item1", synonym: "item2" }
{ _id: 3, fld1: "123", word: "item99", synonym: "item99" }
```

**The Query (from mogo shell):**

```
var arr = [ "item1", "item2" ];

db.matches.aggregate( [
  {
    $addFields: {
        "hasMatches": { $or: [ {$in: [ "$word", arr ]}, {$in: [ "$synonym", arr ]} ] }
       }
   },
   {
     $match: { hasMatches: true }
    }
] )
```

**The Output:**

```
{ "_id" : 1, "fld1" : "blah", "word" : "item2", "synonym" : "item3", "hasMatches" : true }
{ "_id" : 2, "fld1" : "zzz", "word" : "item1", "synonym" : "item2", "hasMatches" : true }
```